# Bash equality not behaving as I expect it

Tags: bash, if-statement

I want to check if last command failed or not in bash. I base this mini script on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29370/how-to-check-if-a-command-succeeded)

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir nothere/cantcreate

echo $?

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "command succeed"
    else
    echo "command failed"
fi
```

This prints the following:

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘nothere/cantcreate’: No such file or
>   directory
>
> 1
>
> command succeed

I expect it to print `command failed` as the value of `$?` is 1. Why does the equality not behave as I expect ?

Comment: Because after `echo $?`, `$?` is the result of the *echo*.

Comment: Of course. Dumb me... @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo $?` itself is command that succeeds printing exit code of failed `mkdir`. If you want to capture exit code of `mkdir` you need to store it right after command call.

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir nothere/cantcreate
RESULT=$?
echo $RESULT

if [ $RESULT -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "command succeed"
else
  echo "command failed"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comment section, when you get to the if-clause `$?` evaluates to the exit code of `echo $?`.

The most straightforward and fool-proof way is to put the command itself in the if-clause:

```
#!/bin/bash
if mkdir nothere/cantcreate; then
    echo "command succeed"
else
    echo "command failed"
fi
```